# How to broadcast a database present on a mobile through LAN?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, webserver

I have a database with a single table named sensors on an android mobile, being continuously updated with real time sensor readings.

I want to make a web server on the mobile so that I can read these readings (database) from another computer on the LAN by entering the mobile's ip.

Is my approach correct? If so, please guide me how to acheive this.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the other way around.

Let the other computer be server with static local IP and make the mobile app send data periodically via POST request to server.